# Can't receive data remotely from one computer

Tags: java, sockets, windows-xp, firewall

So I wrote this jar that interacts with a database and also serves as a server. Problem is that I can only interact with that jar when I'm on the lan or run the jar from a different computer. The system with the problem is running windows xp with the firewall disabled and yes it is correctly set up with the router as I can launch a web server and view it remotely. I have no clue what the problem would be as the firewall is disabled and the jar works on other computers on the same network.

Note: I was noticing an exception "java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol family" earlier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Open Network Connections

2.Right-click any local area connection, and then click Properties.

3.Click Install.

4.In the Select Network Component Type dialog box, click Protocol, and then click Add.

5.In the Select Network Protocol dialog box, click Microsoft TCP/IP version 6, and then click OK

6.Click Close to save changes to your network connection.

Lastly Restart your application

Answer (score 0):

See this: http://www.martinahrer.at/2009/04/16/javanetsocketexception-address-family-not-supported-by-protocol-family-bind/

Generally the problem is related to IPv6 support. Try to google your exception text and I am sure you will find an answer quickly.